# Flutter get localized String by ID

Tags: flutter, localization

I followed the flutter I10n tutorial and I am using `.arb` files for localized strings, and it works perfect for things like this:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.message
```

But how can I get a String by its ID, when I have that string in a variable?
So I need something like this:

```
String txtToTranslate = "message";
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.get(txtToTranslate);
```

but this doesn't exist (at least not to my knowledge). How should I do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this already?

Comment: @PauloPedroso I ended up writing my own AppLocalizations class

Comment: And I ended up using another solution with more flexibility. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'm stuck now on the same problem... :-( No solutions here?!?!